# How can I improve this question on superatoms?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Here's the question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/61606/what-are-the-limits-of-superatom-engineering).

It wasn't received completely well and many people think it could use improvement - but much of the feedback did not give me specifics, and the question remains closed.

What could I do to improve?
Z

Comment: Your question has 4 reopen votes at the time of this comment. Just give it time. I didn't see it in the review queue, only through this question, so thanks for bringing it to the community's attention.

Comment: @Frostfyre the question was abandoned at 4. I'm going to give it one last go.